# 3 table relationship

Tags: c#, database, join, relationship, code-first

I'm trying to estabilish relationship between 3 tables in c#
My models are:
Guitar:

```
public class Guitar
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30)]
    [Required]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int? Price { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
```

Brand:

```
public class Brand
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual ICollection<Guitar> Guitars { get; set; }
    public Brand()
    {
        Guitars = new HashSet<Guitar>();
    }
```

Purchase:(Some properties might be missing here)

```
public class Purchase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(40)]
    public string BuyerName { get; set; }
    
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual Guitar Guitar { get; set; }
    public int GuitarId { get; set; }
    

}
```

I've managed to link the guitar and the brand tables together, but I can't deal with the third one.
Here's my code so far:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Guitar>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasOne(guitar => guitar.Brand)
                .WithMany(brand => brand.Guitars)
                .HasForeignKey(guitar => guitar.BrandId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
        });
```

Foreign key in Purchases table should be the ID of the guitar, but if you have a better idea I'm open to it.
So, how do I do the same with the Purchases?

Answer (score 0):

remove all [NotMapped] from your classes, And I would add a Buyer class too

```
public class Guitar
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ....
  [Required]
     public int? BrandId { get; set; }
     public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
  
}
  public class Brand
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
     .....
   
    public virtual ICollection<Guitar> Guitars { get; set; }

    public Brand()
    {
        Guitars = new HashSet<Guitar>();
    }
}

public class Buyer
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
     [Required]
    [MaxLength(40)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
   
    public virtual ICollection<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
    public Bayer()
    {
        Purchases = new HashSet<Purchase>();
    }
}

public class Purchase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? BuyerId { get; set; }
     public virtual Buyer Buyer { get; set; }

       [Required]
    public int? GuitarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Guitar Guitar { get; set; }
}
```

and if your are using net core 5+ you don't need any fluent apis